# Swap contents of a sidebar page with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a problem that I can't quite get my head around.

I've built 3 identical templates in my CMS except for the CSS that they call (it's not WordPress and has no access to the application layer). I have plugged in my navigation, sidebar and footer in the theme files (think of these as "pages" in a WordPress site rather than the PHP shortcodes one would normally use). My page content is then dynamically served.

My issue is that these templates are going to be used across a number of different websites. Thus the contents of the navigation, sidebar and footer all need to be able to change depending on which site they are in use on. The business requirements are that I have to have only one of each of these pages. I can't just make 20 copies of the theme if I were to have to do 20 websites.

My initial idea is to use something like this....

```
    var url = window.location.href;
    var site1 = url.indexOf('site1');
    var site2 = url.indexOf('anothersite');
    var site3 = url.indexOf('thefinalsite');
    if (site1 >= 0) {
        $('.sidebar_info').append('<a href=""><li>Login</li></a><br/><a href=""><li>Another Link</li></a>');            
    }
    else if (site2 >= 0) {
        $('.sidebar_info').append('<a href=""><li>Not Login</li></a><br/><a href=""><li>Link</li></a>');            
    }
    else if (site3 >= 0) {
        $('.sidebar_info').append('<a href=""><li>Unique Link</li></a><br/><a href=""><li>Some other Link</li></a>');            
    }
    else {
         $('.sidebar_info').append('<a href=""><li>Nothing</li></a>'); 
    }
```

While I'm pretty sure I could make this work it would be a headache if every time a site was commissioned to be built I have to go into 3 different pages and update the functions. Plus ideally down the line a less technical person would be able to spin one of these up themselves.

Any ideas on other ways I could accomplish this with JS or jQuery?

Much appreciated!

Comment: you can make this script at centralized and call this like we call CDN !

Comment: By using this you have to change your script at one place

Comment: @SunilKumar thats true! and that would mean I only have to change the script in one place but then the issue still remains that a non technical person would have to be able to manage it going forward. That may end up being the route I go though if i can't find another way. Thanks for reply!

Comment: Do the set of links follow any sort of consistent pattern across the different sites? Do the links appear anywhere else within the body of the page?